# Update a row in CSV from another CSV when ID match

Tags: python, list, dataframe, csv

I have two `.csv` files with a diffrent size. In `csv_input` is a column `'EAN'`. In the second `.csv` is another column `'ean'`. When the number from `csv_input` match with `csv_output` it should update(means copy text from `csv_input` "Beschreibung"-column and overwrite it with the actual text in the row where the EAN<->ean match is `csv_output` `'description_long'`.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_input = 'beschreibung.csv'
csv_output = 'shop2.csv'

fieldsinput = ['EAN', 'Beschreibung']
fieldsoutput = ['ean', 'description_long']

dfi = pd.read_csv(csv_input, sep=";",  usecols=fieldsinput)
dfo = pd.read_csv(csv_output, sep=";",  usecols=fieldsoutput)
   

comparevalues = dfi.EAN.values() == dfo.ean.values()
print(comparevalues)
```

I tried this so far just to check if i can compare IDs but get the error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Iam also had a idea of merge the `.csv`

```
df_all = pd.merge(dfi, dfo, left_on='EAN', right_on='ean')

for row in df_all:
....
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do the equivalent of a relational join.  Look up:  Join-Object.  There are numerous PS users who have posted something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Takes two CSV's groups two columns from first dict `Unique Card ID` and `mac`

then compares it to see if there is a match from second dict for `Bluetooth code`

If a match is found, it will inject the first dict `mac` into the empty column

`client_mac` next to the `Bluetooth code` code that it matches on from the first dictionary

```
import pandas as pd

df_firstDict = pd.read_csv("seeds/Card Test Data - Sheet1.csv")
dict_compare = {row["Unique Card ID"]: row["MAC"] 
for index, row in df_firstDict[['Unique Card ID', 'MAC']].iterrows()}


df_secondDict = pd.read_csv("seeds/SalasTestData - Sheet1.csv")
df_compare = df_secondDict["Bluetooth code"].map(lambda x: dict_compare.get(x))
df_secondDict.drop(columns=["client_mac"], inplace=True)
df_secondDict["client_mac"] = df_compare

print(dict_compare)
```